# Intel RAID verification and repair

Tags: raid, intel-rst

Intel has a [web page](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-023081.htm) that describes how its Rapid Storage Technology verifies and repairs RAID volumes.

For RAID 1 and RAID 10, it does the following:

> Data on the mirror is compared to data on the source.  If the data on the mirror does not match the data on the source, the data on the mirror is overwritten with the data on the source.

For RAID 5, it does the following:

> Parity is recalculated and compared to the stored parity for that stripe.  If the newly calculated parity does not match the stored parity, the stored parity is overwritten with the newly calculated parity.

My questions:

1) For RAID 1 and RAID 10, what if it's the source that contains corrupted data - will it really copy that corrupted data onto the mirror, causing the correct data to be lost?

2) For RAID 5, what if corrupted data was used to recalculate the parity - will it really overwrite the old correct parity with the new incorrect parity?

Answer (score 3):

[According to an Intel employee](https://communities.intel.com/thread/55724), Intel RAID really could overwrite correct data with incorrect data when doing a verify and repair.  [Apparently all RAID systems are like this.](https://superuser.com/a/587917/115033)